# Get Data from SharePoint list and insert into MasterPage

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, master-pages, sharepoint-designer

I'm working on a SharePoint Foundation 2013 Project.

I'd like to get Data from a SharePoint list - which works for me.

But how do I insert it into a HTML attribute?

**For example:**
Here I get the Content from SharePoint List

```
<SharePoint:FieldValue FieldName="SEO_Keywords" runat="server"/>
```

The Output is like: Apple, Orange, Banana, Lime

I'd like to put it like this:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="Apple, Orange, Banana, Lime"/>
```

This one dont work:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="<SharePoint:FieldValue FieldName="SEO_Keywords" runat="server"/>/>
```

Thanks for you Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this, it's not the best soloution, but it will work for you.

```
<meta name="keywords" content="<%-- <!-- --%><SharePoint:FieldValue FieldName="SEO_Keywords" runat="server"/><%-- --> --%>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to build a small user control to achieve such dynamic addition of meta keywords.

See here for one such example:

http://tracyswebdesign.blogspot.in/2013/02/add-metadata-tags-in-sharepoint-2010-to.html